# Run crontab with user input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

i created a crontab which will run a bash script test.sh. This test.sh file requires some input from the user, and saves the user input into a variable. How do i ensure that the user input will be saved to a variable in test.sh, and when crontab runs the script i can get the output i want?

for e.g i have 2 files, file1.sh and file2.sh. i put file2.sh in file 1.sh. i then run file1.sh, get the user input, and save it somewhere. crontab will run file2.sh, and retrieve the value from the "*saved somewhere variable*". is there anyway for this?

Answer (score 5):

If the input is read by the script from `stdin`, just redirect input from a file (using a wrapper script).

```
#! /bin/sh
test.sh < data.in
```

If this does not work for you (i.e. you have your script calling some interactive shell program like telnet, you can use [`Expect`](http://expect.nist.gov/) to automate the interaction.

Answer (score 1):

1. `file1.sh` gets user input and writes it to `/etc/file2.dat`
2. `file2.sh` reads `/etc/file2.dat` and does whatever it needs

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a strange thing to do. Ask yourself these questions:

Do you really want a popup asking the user for an input value every time the cron runs?

What happens when there's no one at the keyboard?

Comment: what if for e.g i have 2 files, file1.sh and file2.sh. i put file2.sh in file 1.sh. i then run file1.sh, get the user input, and save it somewhere. crontab will run file2.sh, and retrieve the value from the *saved somewhere variable*. is there anyway for this?

Comment: I've run into a case where it would be useful: an automated git commit script. The cron runs very frequently, but the popup is only required occasionally (as a simplification, if there are changes to commit and nothing has changed for at least 5 minutes). What would be nice would be user input to grab a commit message so that everything doesn't just have an "auto commit" message. If user input isn't received after a certain period of time, the script should fallback to a default value.