# How to generate an auto answer to a script running from cron

Tags: shell, response, cron

I want to run a shell script from cron, and have it answered automatically. How do I do that?

I tried to put on crontab a script. The system is Linux.
One command of the script prompt a question and must be answered ( Y/N )
Ex : 
When the script is executed manually, the script execute the command.
The command prompt the question : Do you intend to delete ? [Y/N] 
and the system wait for the response.
I answer "Y" and press ENTER, then the script execute the deletion.

I intend to put this script on crontab.
I wish the command will be answered automatically Yes.
How can I do on crontab ?
Many thanks
/Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149858/run-crontab-with-user-input.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

1. The command may have a switch to not prompt the question. E.g. `rm` has the switch `-f` (force), so that using `rm -f $file` won't prompt anything. I'd prefer this option if possible.
2. Use the [yes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) command, which exists exactly for this case. For example, `yes | rm foo` will automatically answer `y` to the prompt by `rm` if any.

Comment: Yeah, `yes` works for me.  I used for install pytorch like this `yes | conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch`.

Answer (score 3):

### Generic Cron with Pipes

Most shells have access to a *yes* command. You can pipe it into your script in the cron job.

```
* * * * * yes | myscript.sh
```

### Vixie Cron and Standard Input

In addition to the above, if you are using vixie-cron, you can also use the percent sign to feed standard input into your commands. crontab(5) says:

> Percent-signs (%) in the  command,
>   unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline
>   characters, and all data after the first % will be sent  to
>   the  command  as standard  input.  There  is  no way to split a
>   single command line onto multiple lines, like the shell's trailing
>   "\".

With vixie-cron, the following example would pass the letter "y" on standard input to your script:

```
* * * * * myscript.sh % y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

> --interactive=0

at the end of the command. This will automatically return yes for any cron command asking yes/no.